# Can a Flutter app be proposed on the KaiOS apps store?

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications, kaios

When building a Flutter app for iOS or Android or both, one may wish to build it for KaiOS as well.
Flutter allows the generation of web applications.
KaiOS accepts web applications in its apps store.

I am wondering whether it is possible for a Flutter app to be accepted on the KaiOS apps store.

Comment: I was asking myself a similar question and found this article about it. Maybe not a definitive answer to both of your questions but definitely a good summary to Flutter development on KaiOS: https://jod.li/2021/05/01/flutter-on-kaios/

Comment: @devEnju thanks. I wrote this article. You are right, this is not a definitive answer because it is missing the crucial validation part. The reason is that this example app is not yet validated by the KaiStore staff.

Comment: Very interesting and also a very good read. Thanks for sharing your experience, that definitely opened my eyes about the efforts which would have to go into the button mappings and already saved a lot of time. Unfortunately, I'm completely unfamiliar with the requirements for the KaiStore but maybe some officials or the community can give an answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment @devEnju ! I'm glad you enjoyed this article. These is one important addition I would make once the app gets approved or not, The KaiAds requirement is not optional. I thought that it was "If you have ads, it must be KaiAds". Well, no, it is more "You must have KaiAds". Which I was able to add to my Flutter chat app. Also, they explained that email validation will severely reduce the number of users because KaiOS phone users often don't use emails. SMS validation is preferred.

Comment: This is a tech support question, not a question about programming. The appropriate people to ask are the ones who operate the store in question (perhaps indirectly, for example by reading their documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your help @KarlKnechtel . Unfortunately, the KaiOS store staff doesn't have the right answer. I only got something like "we don't support Flutter" with no reason. In fact, technically, there is no reason it should be any different from a simple HTML application and it works fine. The Flutter application I proposed was not validated but not rejected either. I believe the best place for this question is SO and not reddit or something like that. If you read the article mentioned in the first comment, you will see this question has a lot of programming implications.

Comment: " I only got something like "we don't support Flutter" with no reason." Your question was whether you could host the app. They told you no. How is that not an answer?

Comment: Indeed, one may think this is an answer if one doesn't know Flutter or KaiOS or the context. It is like mentionning soccer to a football player and getting a "I don't play soccer!" while soccer and football are the same thing. The reason is that it works and I got no rejection nor any reason for not being accepted.